# How can I successfully display this PNG image pulled from an array? (Poor understanding of PIL)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, png

I am trying to store a set of png images in an array and later display them when needed. I am initially importing png files from local storage and storing as type '_io.BytesIO'.
I can then create an object of type 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile' using Image.open() which responds to display().

See working code:

```
byts = import_png(raw_string)
im = Image.open(byts)
display(im)

def import_png(raw_string):
    """input = string, output = '_io.BytesIO' type
    The output is to be displayable as image for testing and storable in array"""
    byteImgIO = io.BytesIO()
    byteImg = Image.open(raw_string)
    byteImg.save(byteImgIO, "PNG")
    byteImgIO.seek(0)
    byteImg = byteImgIO.read()
    dataBytesIO = io.BytesIO(byteImg)
    return dataBytesIO
```

I am failing to do the above for multiple png's stored in an array. See below:

```
array = np.zeros((3,24,24)) #3 test images of size 24x24 pixels
for id in range (0,3):
    byts = import_png(raw_string)
    im = Image.open(byts)
    array[id] = im
test_id = 0
array[test_id] = array[test_id].astype(np.uint8) #ensuring correct datatype
im = Image.fromarray(array[test_id]) # produces type 'PIL.Image.Image' with mode = 'F'
if im.mode != 'RGB':
    im = im.convert('RGB')
print(str(im)) #Gives <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=24x24 at 0x1DEEDCB72B0>
display(im) # Fails to display by just showing black box
```

I know that something is going wrong with the data conversion, as curiously running the line below adjusts the image to be *almost* the original.

```
array[test_id] = 255-(array[test_id]*255/8)
```

Edit: @mark-setchell

I’ll try to be more clear. The ultimate goal of this block of code is to import png files from my computer and store them efficiently such that they can be displayed and used to train a neural network.

- I had trouble simply importing the images for display, hence my code to convert to ‘_io.BytesIO’ for display.
- Also I was unable to write the Bytes object to an array hence the confusing flow where I convert back to image with im = Image.open(byts).

If you can suggest the pythonic way to get rid of the above I would be grateful.

Given your comment about mode ‘F’ being inconsistent with a png file I think I may have a mistake in the following code:

```
im = Image.open(byts)
array[test_id] = array[test_id].astype(np.uint8) #ensuring correct datatype
im = Image.fromarray(array[test_id])
```

The above code creates a 'PIL.Image.Image' mode = 'F' rather than the 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile' which successfully displays.

**Edit #2**

The goal remains the same. I want to take a folder of 10000 png files (RGBA) and efficiently read them and carry out some basic deep learning.

I have fixed my initial hacky code such that dealing with bytes is not needed, with code below. A key fix was recognizing that the correct mode is RGBA.

```
def image_id_to_image(id):
    """Input = id integer, 
    Output = RGBA image file of shape (24, 24, 4)"""
    raw_str = image_id_to_raw_str(id)
    im = Image.open(raw_str)
    #display(im) #if you wish to check whats going on
    im = im.convert('RGBA')
    return im
```

I have also now managed to store all 10000 .png files in a .h5 file for more convenient and efficient reading.

```
def store_many_hdf5(images, labels):
    """ Stores an array of images to HDF5.
        Parameters:
        ---------------
        images       images array, (N, 24, 24, 4) to be stored
        labels       labels array, (N, 1) to be stored
    """
    num_images = len(images)

    # Create a new HDF5 file
    hdf5_dir = fr"PATH"
    file = h5py.File(hdf5_dir, "w")

    # Create a dataset in the file
    dataset = file.create_dataset(
        "images", np.shape(images), h5py.h5t.STD_U8BE, data=images
    )
    meta_set = file.create_dataset(
        "meta", np.shape(labels), h5py.h5t.STD_U8BE, data=labels
    )
    file.close()

test_img_count =6
image_array = np.zeros((test_img_count,24,24,4))
labels = np.zeros((test_img_count,1))

for i in range(0,test_img_count):
    image = image_id_to_image(i)
    image_array[i,:,:,:] = image
    labels[i] = "%03d" % i

store_many_hdf5(images = image_array, labels = labels)
```

I have also managed to successfully display multiple images from the created h5 file

```
hdf5_dir = fr"PATH.h5"
multi_image_hdf5 = h5py.File(hdf5_dir, "r")

multi_images = np.array(multi_image_hdf5["images"])
multi_labels = np.array(multi_image_hdf5["meta"])

filename = hdf5_dir

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(24,24))
for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(multi_images[i].astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is trying to do at all. If you have a PNG image that is showing up as mode `F` you have problems because `F` is `float` and PNG doesn't support floats, only 8/16 bit pixels. You also appear to read a PNG-encoded image from disk and decode it into a PIL Image then re-encode it for some reason back into a PNG-encoded memory buffer - that is surely pointless, you may as well just `read()` the PNG-encoded bytes directly from disk. Please try to be clearer about what you are really trying to do so we can help you better. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Mark, I have updated my post to address your comments. Hopefully it clears some things up, thanks for response.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. If you want to display `image.png` which is a file on disk, why not do `im = Image.open('image.png')` and display it? Why are you making BytesIO and arrays?

Comment: @3Turner can we have an axample of raw_string , because from here:  byteImg = Image.open(raw_string) seems to me that is actually an image file and not a string ? sorry but I am a newbie too

Comment: @MarkSetchell I now understand your confusion and appreciate you not just simply fixing my code. My code was showing a poor understanding and was just confusing/non-sensical. With that being said I have managed to do what I wanted. I'm unsure if this post will be of any value to others and am considering deleting, what do you think?

Comment: We all have much to learn. Your question is doing no harm and may help others - don't rush to delete it. Experience is what you get when you don't get what you wanted.